# How can I parse timestamp with time zone?

Tags: python, pyarrow, apache-arrow

**What I am trying to do**

I am using [Py Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/) to parse data from a csv (originally from a Postgres database). I am having issues parsing a timestamp (with a timezone) that looks like `2017-08-19 14:22:11.802755+00`.

I am then receiving an error that looks like:

`pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: In CSV column #11: CSV conversion error to timestamp[ns]: invalid value '2017-08-19 12:22:11.802755+00'`

**What I have tried to do**

I tried using a specified parser for the data, so this is how I read the csv (snippet for brevity):

```py
    arrow_table = arrow_csv.read_csv(
        input_file=input_buffer,
        convert_options=arrow_csv.ConvertOptions(
            timestamp_parsers=[ISO8601, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N %z"],# I have also tried omitting this
            column_types=arrow_schema,
            strings_can_be_null=True,  
            true_values=['t'],  
            false_values=['f'], 
        )
    )
```

Not that in `column_types` I map the column that I want to parse like (I am mapping Postgres types to Arrow types, which works for all other types except for this):

```
timestamp with time zone': pa.timestamp('ns', tz="+00:00")
```

But none of that seems to work. I'm happy to provide further information if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortuantely, Arrow's IOS8601 parser does not support offset strings.  The strptime parser is based on the [2008 POSIX definition of strptime](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html) via vendored [musl](https://github.com/esmil/musl) which does not support `%z`.  Some implementations of strptime do include support (e.g. the libc implementation)

This seems like a valid feature request for either parser.  I've filed [ARROW-13348](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-13348) to track this.

For workarounds, your best bet may be parsing the column as strings and using some other library (pandas?) to convert to Timestamps.